# Glossaries as makeindex

Tags: glossaries, makeindex

I'm trying to use the package [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to create an index of notations. But I have some requirements which I don't know how to implement using [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

1. The default way of [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to introduce a new entry is to write it manually at the preamble. However, I want the entry to be added to the index when I defined it in the main text. By the way, the same notation may have been defined various times with different meanings in many parts of the article, so I want them all to be added to the index.
2. The default usage of an entry is `\gls...`, which will create a hyperlink to the glossary. However, I don't want it and instead, I want there to be hyperlinks (at least labels) in the index referring to where the notation is defined in the main text.

I find that these features are actually very like to just use `makeindex`. So hopefully this is a simple question.

Comment: I realize it’s been a while. If you’d still like an answer, it might help to show us an example of what you have so far.